# Buttons are not in same size

Tags: java, android, eclipse, button, user-interface

I have created an application with buttons of "same size" and I added images to it which are also in the same size. Following is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/fBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/fStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/rBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/rStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/sStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/cStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/aStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/lStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/oBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/oStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/tStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/eBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/eStr" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/dStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/hStr" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/aBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="@string/aStr" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the problem is, it does not generate what I expected. Following is how it get displayed in eclipse editor

[image]

Following is how it get displayed in emulator

[image]

As you can see, first column and third column are bigger than the second column. But what I expected is columns in same size.

Following is my `strings.xml` file in case it is helpful

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>


<string name="fStr">Fffffffff</string>
<string name="rStr">Rrrrrr</string>
<string name="sStr">Ssssss       </string>
<string name="cStr">Ccccccc</string>
<string name="aStr">Aaaaaaa</string>
<string name="lStr">Lllll</string>
<string name="oStr">Oooooooooooo</string>
<string name="tStr">Ttttt</string>
<string name="eStr">Eeeeee</string>
<string name="dStr">Dddddddddd</string>
<string name="cStr">Cccccccc</string>
<string name="hStr">Hhhh</string>
<string name="aStr">Aaaaaaaaaa aaaa</string>

</resources>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: for the button you are using the weight property and widht="wrap_content". Try with layout_width="0dip" instead of wrap_content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `layout_width` to 0dp, that's fixed this issue for me before.

Comment: yep, setting it to `0dp` or `0dip` should make it use weights instead. Else you are overriding the weight property. +1

Comment: You mean "layout_width"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But layout width of what?

Comment: The width of whatever element you have the weight applied to.

Answer (score 1):

Change all the `Button` `android:layout_width` to `fill_parent`

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buttonssssssssssssssssssssssss" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buttonssssssssssssssssssssssss" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buttonssssssssssssssssssssssss" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout:width attribute of the table row with fill parent

```
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I agree and recommend the use of `layout_weight` where you have to make a distribution or divide width among the `view` objects.

Also looking at your code I would suggest using lesser views as you are using `TableLayout` that is not actually required if you just use a `LinearLayout` with three buttons and use the above mentioned property properly.

I am also not sure why you actually need `RelativeLayout` in this case. If you go by hierarchy-viewer tool from android-sdk then you will come to know the lesser the number of views you are using a layout the low memory your screen will use and hence responsive.

The latter one is just a suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this issue adding

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

and into your LinearLayout(here) you can add your blocks with: `android:layout_width="0.0dip"`
if you want to put some margin between the blocks... use: `android:layout_marginLeft="sizehere.0dip"` `android:layout_marginRight="sizehere.0dip"`

```
</LinearLayout>
```